# SQL script on server side to select row with given credentials

Tags: c++, sql

If I have a sql database with a table called `users`, how do I go about accessing a row by giving credentials?

There are three columns: `username`, `password`, and `age`. I don't want `age` to be accessible to everyone. I know how to search a row by using `username`, but the database should also require you to enter a password that matches the user. I know that this can easily be done on the client side, but clients can be modified and it becomes useless. If it matters, I'm using c++ for the client.

Here's an example of the table

```
| username | password | age |
―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
|  johnny  | Abcd123! | 031 |
―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――
|  thomas  | Xyz1234! | 076 |
```

I need a script or something on the server side, that will only allow me to search a row by entering both the `username` and `password` correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
     Select * from table where username = &username
     and password = &password
```

Eg something like below

```
   cin >> username
   cin >> password
    Resultset="Select * from table where username =" 
     +username+ "and password =" +password
```

Comment: Do I put this into a script in the server? How do I go about doing that?